# error Couldn't find package "create-vuepress" on the "npm" registry

Tags: yarnpkg, vuepress

Based on this guide:

https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/getting-started.html#quick-start

I am trying to create a new vuepress project with:

```
$ yarn create vuepress sample-docs
```

But I get:

```
$ yarn create vuepress sample-docs
yarn create v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "create-vuepress" on the "npm" registry.
```

No hits on google for that error. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your Node.js version?

Comment: If you try `npx create-vuepress [directoryName]`, happen any error? But I prefer to create project manually (https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/getting-started.html#manual-setup)